# Dynamic table names

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a database that my program will query.

it has 3 tables all with the same structure:
table1, table2 table3

How can I write a linq query that will query each of these table, with my dynamically specifying the tablename?

In addition to this.  This solution must work if additional tables are added to the database.  So even though when I was writing the code table4 did not exist it may get added.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an array of table names, and then pull from that (i.e. use a foreach on the array of table names, and then run that query with that element of the array as the name)?

Comment: [Some hacks are talked about here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/linqprojectgeneral/thread/6273d072-f500-4382-afb4-8eafd185794d). YMMV. Good luck.

Comment: if the tables all have the same structure, why not have just one table, with an extra column indicating the 'type' of the record (previously indicated by which table the record belonged to)? Then you would be able to specify the record 'type' in the where clause of your LINQ query.

Comment: I'm afraid that the added rows will slow down the query no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
      DataSet s = new DataSet ();
      DataTable t1 = new DataTable ();
      t1.Columns.Add ("A", typeof (int));
      t1.Columns.Add ("B", typeof (string));
      s.Tables.Add (t1);
      t1.Rows.Add (1, "T1");
      t1.Rows.Add (2, "T1");

      DataTable t2 = new DataTable ();
      t2.Columns.Add ("A", typeof (int));
      t2.Columns.Add ("B", typeof (string));
      s.Tables.Add (t2);
      t2.Rows.Add (1, "T2");
      t2.Rows.Add (2, "T2");
      t2.Rows.Add (3, "T2");

      var result = from t in s.Tables.OfType<DataTable> ()
                   from r in t.Rows.OfType<DataRow> ()
                   select r;
```